# Elasticsearch client does not fetch result when a single client node goes down

Tags: elasticsearch

We have a very standard elasticsearch setup with 3 master nodes, 6 data nodes and 3 client nodes. Here is our connection code for connecting to Elasticsearch clients from our Java application.

```
    Settings settings = Settings.settingsBuilder()
            .put("cluster.name", configuration.getString("clusterName"))
            .put("client.transport.sniff", false)
            .put("client.transport.ping_timeout", "5s")
            .build();

    TransportClient client = TransportClient.builder().settings(settings).build();

    for (String hostname : (Collection<String>)configuration.get("hostnames")){
        try {
            client = client.addTransportAddresses(
                    new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(hostname), 9300)
            );
            break;
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

We have currently three different host in hostnames list. But any time a single client from this list of hostname goes down this Elasticsearch transport client stops responding. I have gone through transport client documentation on Elasticsearch site and have also tried looking at their Github issues, according to that whenever a node goes down only elasticsearch should remove it from list of nodes and continue working with other nodes, but in our case things just break down. Anyone has any idea what might be the problem?
We are using elasticsearch 2.4.3 right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are breaking the loop after a single node has been added. Try removing the break statement:

```
for (String hostname : (Collection<String>)configuration.get("hostnames")){
        try {
            client = client.addTransportAddresses(
                    new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(hostname), 9300)
            );
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: holy shit!!! it was so simple. May be i was just stuck in a box that my can not be wrong.

Comment: @Hardik127 Happens with the best of us! Sometimes we miss out the most silly things. Cheers!